# I'm getting the result I wanted followed by "None"

Tags: python

I would like to get rid of `None` but I don't know what is my mistake here...

```
def job(hours,rate):
       if hours < 40:
           sm = hours * rate
           print(sm)
       elif hours > 40:
           sm = 40 * rate
           ov = ((hours - 40) * rate) * 0.5
           tt = sm + ov
           print(tt)
       
a = float(input())
b = float(input())

print(job(a,b))
print("Fine")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens as you are printing a function that does not return anything. Just call the function, do not print it, as without the `return` statement, a function returns `None` by default, you can update the function to add a `return` statement :

```
def job(hours,rate):
       if hours < 40:
           sm = hours * rate
           return sm
       elif hours > 40:
           sm = 40 * rate
           ov = ((hours - 40) * rate) * 0.5
           tt = sm + ov
           return tt
       
a = float(input())
b = float(input())

print(job(a,b))
print("Fine")
```